# working with .scroll() in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this, so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.

```
<div class="mytest" >
       <!-- some code -->
</div>

<script>
  $(window).scroll(function(){
     if( $(this).scrollTop() > 600 ){
       // Here is my script
     }
  });
</script>
```

its working fine only but i want make it the scroll is after div.mytest

that means

```
   <script>
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       if( ----- ){ // div.mytest tag is over 
         // Here is my script
       }
    });
   </script>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Take a location of that one and do the same which you have done at first one

Comment: You want the div to scroll instead of the body ?

Comment: @Lorenzo no now its working the page height is greater than 600px right, I want to make the scroll is cross the div.mytest

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of function which takes array of HTML elements and scrolls to uppermost of them. See how it uses `offset().top` method to define scroll position.

```
function scrollTo(els){
    var maxTop = 0;
    $.each(els, function(i, el){
        maxTop = Math.max(maxTop, el.offset().top);
    });
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: maxTop
    }, 400);
}
```